# Making bit identical ext2 filesystems

Tags: filesystems, mkfs, ext2, reproducible-build

I'm preparing an image file for a linux system. I need to be able to run my script that creates the image and have the output be bit-for-bit identical each time.

I do the normal procedure, by making a large binary file, partition it, create  a loop device with the partition and then make the I filesystem. I then `mount` the file system, copy the *syslinux* and *initrd* stuff over, unmount  the partition, delete the loop devices and I have my image file. I can `dd` it to a disk and the linux system boots correctly. So I'm making the filesystem correctly.

I run my script that performs the above steps but each time the output differs. Some of it is timestamps in the *ext2* data structures. I wrote a program that reads in the *ext2* structures and can clear out the timestamps, and `tune2fs` can clear out a few more things but some of the bitmap data even differs and it seems the file data isn't even in the same place each time.

So how would I go about creating identical filesystems?

Here's the commands I use to create a filesystem, put a file on it and unmount it. Save the output and run it again, then compare the outputs, the file `a.txt` gets put in different locations.

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1024 count=46112 of=cf.bin
parted cf.bin <<EOF
unit
s
mklabel
msdos
mkpart
p
ext2
63s
45119s
set
1
boot
on
q
EOF

losetup -o $(expr 63 \* 512) /dev/loop0 cf.bin

mke2fs -b 1024 -t ext2 /dev/loop0 22528

#clear some parameters
tune2fs -i 0 /dev/loop0 # interval between check
tune2fs -L LABEL /dev/loop0
tune2fs -U 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 /dev/loop0 #uuid
tune2fs -c 0 /dev/loop0 #mount count

mount /dev/loop0 mnt
# make a dummy file
echo HELLO > mnt/a.txt
umount mnt

losetup -d /dev/loop0
```

Update
If I put the above commands in a script, copy and paste them to run a second time (but save the output between), and even change the date before running the commands a 2nd time (using the `date` command), the *a.txt* gets put in the same disk location. But if you run the script, save the output, and run it again from the command line, compare the outputs and *a.txt* is in different locations. Very curious behavior. What data is being used to generate the file locations? Clearly it's not the time. The only thing I can think of is the difference between calling the commands twice via calling the script twice vs running the commands twice in the same script would be something like the process ID of the calling process. Ideas anyone?

Update #2
I gave up on trying to use ext2. So I can't answer my original question about ext2, but I'll describe what I did to get a completely reproducible build of a basic linux system.

1. Instead of ext2, use a FAT variant or ISO9660. If you need a partition less than 32MB, use FAT16 for the linux system partition, otherwise use FAT32. Either FAT16 or FAT32 will repeatedly put files in the same locations. But it does have some time stamps in its directory entries.
2. Add linux system files needed to boot.
3. Write a program to walk the FAT16/32 filesystem directory structures and set all time stamps to 0.
4. Clear the disk signature in the mbr. Either do this in your program that clears timestamps, or use dd.
5. Since it's a FAT filesystem, I'm using syslinux for a boot loader. cpio will produce identical initrd's from run to run, so there's no issues there. This is all that is needed for a basic bit-for-bit identical linux system.

#### Issues with FAT file systems

For just booting a linux system, FAT shouldn't cause any problems. But for larger data partitions, there are a couple issues with FAT32 that may crop up.

1. It is possible to bump into the maximum number of files in a directory. This isn't likely to be a problem. (but of course, in my case it was)
2. FAT32 will store an 8.3 filename for each file. Long file names are shortened to a stem with a tilde and a number appended. But if you have more than 9 files that map to the same short stem, FAT32 uses an undocumented procedure to generate a sort of hash to append to the file name instead. I dug into the linux kernel code for FAT32, and it uses the time as a hash seed (the function`vfat_create_shortname()` in file namei_vfat.c). So this field is not reproducible. I don't know how Microsoft's implementation does it. You may get away with just clearing this field, as I don't think the 8.3 names are used for anything other than DOS. Or you could generate your own unique numbers that you can reproduce, it doesn't matter what the numbers are, just that they're unique.

Using ISO9660 for an additional partition

1. Use genisoimage to create the iso. It will generate identical output from run to run with the exception of time stamps. Using the -l option lets you have file names of up to 31 character. If you need filenames longer than that, use the rock ridge extension. The command is

   ```
   genisoimage -o gfx.iso -R -l -f assets/files/
   ```
2. Write a program that walks the iso9660 filesystem, clears all time stamps, including the TF field of the rock ridge entries.
3. Use fdisk or parted to make a partition in your disk image. 96h is the MBR id number for ISO9660.
4. If necessary, patch up the partition table. Parted doesn't support making a partition of type iso9660. Unfortunately, I'm stuck with an older version of both parted and fdisk, and parted is easier to use. So I used parted to make my second partition as fat32. Then used fdisk to change the type to 96.
5. Use dd to embed the iso in the disk image, using the same numbers you used for making the partition. I used

   ```
   dd bs=512 seek=$part2_start_lba conv=notrunc if=gfx.iso of=cf.bin
   ```

where cf.bin is my disk image file.
6. Mount the iso partition after linux has booted. If the iso is the second partition, it will be /dev/sda2. You may have to use mknod to make the proper device file in /dev first.

Comment: Why are you recreating the filesystem? Why not make copies of a single image instead? If you are updating files in the filesystem, you can't make a bit-by-bit identical copy (the file may be placed in different location on the disk, as you discovered, and obviously the updated files would be different).

Comment: I'm working on a system for a regulated industry (Casino Gaming). I have to submit my software along with the source, and the State has to rebuild the software and their output should match the original software I submit.. All the pieces of my system match, I just can't put them into a whole correctly.

Comment: After creating a fresh filesystem, and you go to copy a file to it, shouldn't the process be deterministic and put the file in the same spot each time? Sure, time stamps & uuidd's will change, but if the file system was created with the same parameters each time, the group descriptors, inode and block bitmaps, and inode tables should be in the same spots, no?

Comment: One possible perturbation source is the `s_hash_seed` which is used for hashing directory indexes. It seems to be set to a random number using function `uuid_generate()` (as it is a 16 byte field).

Comment: What command are you using exactly? Have you read and followed [the process for reproducible builds](https://reproducible-builds.org/docs/system-images/)?

Comment: meuh - I cleared the s_hash_seed in both copies of my superblock after creating the filesystem, then copied a file and saved the output. Then I recreated it all, cleared the fields, copy a file and it still puts them in different locations each time. Good thought though.

Comment: Gilles - I added the commands to my post, I'm looking through that reproducible builds guide you linked to, but it seems to be short on details for ext2, only offering make_ext4fs. I believe I'm stuck with ext2 since this is a somewhat legacy project using kernel 2.6.27.5.

Comment: @jhufford You probably shouldn't clear the `s_hash_seed` as this means "uninitialised". Try setting some fixed other value.

Comment: A filesystem isn't "your software".  It's **a container of** your software.

Comment: RonJohn - it can vary by jurisdiction, but some jurisdictions do require the binary disk image to be identical or at the very least list every offset where they differ and explain the differences. The current jurisdiction I'm working in specifies "The Lab needs the ability to build the VGM (Video Gaming Machine) production image from source and match it to the submitted binary to ensure the correct source was analyzed and archived." So it is a touch ambiguous, but "image" generally refers to more than just an executable file. Never-the-less, recreating a filesystem exactly should be doable.

Comment: Could you instead provide an image using a typical readonly filesystem adequate for booting, like squashfs or isofs (cdrom), which can be generated repeatably, and then the system creates an empty ext2 for logging or whatever.

Comment: meuh - That's probably what I'll do, likely just use FAT32, as it's just a couple  minor changes from extlinux to syslinux and FAT32 so far seems to put things in the same spot (more testing needed though), isolinux might be an option too... The project originally used isofs with cdroms and I'm changing it over from that to hdd, and everything is in fact supposed to be read-only (the bios hashes the boot partition on startup to guarantee things are still legit and the entire system just runs out of the initrd). Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: OK base on my proposed answer below and the comments by @Kusalananda that follow. I can only see one thing that *may* account for the `a.txt` moving, might be that you're not using an absolute, or relative path for `mnt`. As otherwise the process seems *quite* consistent. So maybe `./mnt`, `./mnt/`, or `/mnt/` as it applies?

Comment: Since I came up a solution and described it in my post, what's the proper etiquette here? Should I post my solution as an answer and accept it or just leave the question open as is?

Answer (score 3):

IMHO this all seems to be made overly complicated. When [tar](https://manpage.me/?q=tar) alone seems like the obvious solution. tar can create just about any file system, including cdfs (--options cd9660:*). It will also allow you to time stamp the output file to any of that of the most recent `-m || --modification-time`, `--gid id || --gname name`,  `--acls || --no-acls`, `--same-owner || --no-same-owner`, ...

Or you could create your filesystem. Perform a `chown -Rh someone:somegroup .` within your file tree, and `chmod` it to your liking and use either `tar`, or [rsync](https://manpage.me/?apropos=0&q=rsync&manpath=FreeBSD+11.1-RELEASE+and+Ports) to place the file tree into your prepared filesystem. Then everything would be consistent -- same date, same owner/group && perms.

Well that's the way I'd approach something like this. :)

HTH

Comment: This unfortunately does not solve the issue of creating a bit-by-bit reproducible build of the resulting filesystem.  See the comments from the user to the question.  The resulting filesystem image should be _identical_ each time it's built (have the same MD5 checksum, if you so will).

Comment: Hmm. Then I must be overlooking something. My experience with `rsync` has proven to make an *identical* copy of anything I've pointed it at. Including dates, and permissions. In fact a `diff` of the source, and destination confirm that. Am I perhaps misunderstanding you?

Comment: Sure, `rsync` will do all those things so that the files look identical when you look at them, but can you also force `rsync` to use the same inode number every time for the files it write?  If not, the resulting _filesystem_ is not identical.  Likewise, you can not get `rsync` to write the files in particular locations on the disk (at particular offsets). Two runs of the build of the project would therefore result in filesystems that are not the same. The _files_ would look the same, but the disk images would differ. See the user's "Update" at the end of the question.

Comment: OK i added a comment above based on your comment(s), and my observations given the OPs update. One thing I almost added to my proposed solution is `mtree`. But I didn't want to dilute my proposal. But it still occurs to me that it may prove a valuable tool to help with "consistency". There. I said it. :)

Comment: Interesting idea. Because of what Kusalanandra was saying about inodes in ext2, what if one used this tar/rsync approach with FAT16/32 or iso9660? As I explain in my update above,  FAT and iso filesystems do put files in the same location each time. The question is if tar/rsync fully preserves *all* timestamps to produce identical outputs... I already came up with a solution, but I will keep this idea in mind if any problems come up. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your original question is a tool called [genext2fs](https://github.com/bestouff/genext2fs). If you supply the -f switch, then it will create bit-by-bit identical output, given the same input. This is either proven by its own test-suite which compares the created images with a pre-computed md5sum of the correct output or by this test (executed inside the source dir):

```
$ ./genext2fs -f -B 1024 -b 40 -d m4 rootfs.img
$ md5sum rootfs.img
322053a8962acc599eaabb2dfde28783  rootfs.img
$ rm rootfs.img
$ ./genext2fs -f -B 1024 -b 40 -d m4 rootfs.img
$ md5sum rootfs.img
322053a8962acc599eaabb2dfde28783  rootfs.img
```

You can mount the resulting image and check that its content is indeed the same as the packed directory:

```
$ sudo mount rootfs.img /mnt
$ ls -lha /mnt
total 27K
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  root  1.0K Jan  1  1970 .
drwxr-xr-x 25 root  root  4.0K Mar 22 14:56 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 josch josch 1.5K Mar 22 23:05 ac_func_scanf_can_malloc.m4
-rw-r--r--  1 josch josch 2.4K Mar 22 14:24 ac_func_snprintf.m4
drwx------  2 root  root   16K Jan  1  1970 lost+found
$ rmdir /mnt/lost+found
$ diff -rq m4 /mnt
$ echo $?
0
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

*Note*: This will not be a full answer; just a partial one, or, at least, a hint

---

> I need to be able to run my script that creates the image and have the
>   output be bit-for-bit identical each time.

The first problem you have to achieve that, are the `disk signatures` in your `msdos` partition tables (offset of 440 in the **MBR**, *4 bytes long*). If your MBRs are different, your are failing in your goal just at the first sector. Each time you execute `mklabel` inside `parted`, you are generating a new `disk signature`. You can overcome that, overwriting those four bytes with the same random signature, like this:

```
printf RAMDOM_SIGNATURE | xxd -p -r | dd bs=1 count=4 seek=440 of=YOUR_DOT_BIN conv=notrunc 2> /dev/null
```

`RANDOM_SIGNATURE` could be something like `'73396992'`

I've made a little mod to your script, with this fix:

```bsh
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1024 count=46112 of="$1"
parted "$1" <<EOF
unit
s
mklabel
msdos
mkpart
p
ext2
63s
45119s
set
1
boot
on
q
EOF

printf "$2" | xxd -p -r | dd bs=1 count=4 seek=440 of="$1" conv=notrunc 2> /dev/null

losetup -o $(expr 63 \* 512) /dev/loop0 "$1"

mke2fs -b 1024 -t ext2 /dev/loop0 22528

#clear some parameters
tune2fs -i 0 /dev/loop0 # interval between check
tune2fs -L LABEL /dev/loop0
tune2fs -U 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 /dev/loop0 #uuid
tune2fs -c 0 /dev/loop0 #mount count

#mount /dev/loop0 mnt
## make a dummy file
#echo HELLO > mnt/a.txt
#umount mnt

losetup -d /dev/loop0
```

Now, you can call the script like this

```
./script_name BIN_FILE_NAME RANDOM_SIGNATURE
```

Now, if you do this:

```bsh
./test.sh cf00.bin '73396992'
./test.sh cf01.bin '73396992'
./test.sh cf02.bin '73396992'
./test.sh cf03.bin '73396992'
```

and then this:

```bsh
dd if=cf00.bin count=63 2>/dev/null | sha1sum
dd if=cf01.bin count=63 2>/dev/null | sha1sum
dd if=cf02.bin count=63 2>/dev/null | sha1sum
dd if=cf03.bin count=63 2>/dev/null | sha1sum
```

You'll see that all of those files are identical till just before the filesystem in the first partition (try the same with your original script, and the sums will differ from one another).

You probably notice that in my version of the script, I commented out the lines that wrote the `a.txt` file. I did this, cause there is no point in trying to fix that, when you can't make the filesystems identical, even with no files on them. And this is the case: the filesystems differ, even with no files, so, first, we need to fix that.

If you run `dumpe2fs` against the filesystem partition on each image, dump that to a file, and then use `diff` against any pair of dumps, you'll see something like this:

```
25c25
< Filesystem created:       Sat Jun 15 07:37:32 2019
---
> Filesystem created:       Sat Jun 15 07:37:40 2019
27c27
< Last write time:          Sat Jun 15 07:37:33 2019
---
> Last write time:          Sat Jun 15 07:37:40 2019
30c30
< Last checked:             Sat Jun 15 07:37:32 2019
---
> Last checked:             Sat Jun 15 07:37:40 2019
37c37
< Directory Hash Seed:      603130ae-82de-4530-9772-f68ae3d6df5f
---
> Directory Hash Seed:      1d9c5af8-a48e-4221-9e70-8fa2ccc6936f
```

So, at very least, **at a very high level** (after this, you need to go deeper, at the lowest level, i.e.: the actual **byte by byte** comparison ) the filesystems differ in the details showed just above. Get around that first.

Even if you change the date in the machine, you'll no be successful in tampering the timestamps and making them equal, cause there are gaps of time you can control in the program execution. In that case, you'll need to *freeze* your clock, at least, from the program that creates the filesystem perspective. You can dig on that, but I think that this is not the way to go, cause you said that they need to execute your script in their machines: *you don't want to mess with their clock*. So, IMHO, the way to go, is probably tampering the correct bytes on the filesystem, like I did with the `disk signature`. Search around that.

Also, don't forget the `Superblock backups`... track them down. If they contain different data on each filesystem, they will propagate differences in the byte range they reside.

Lastly, bare in mind that when you copy a file, you don't have direct control over the 'distribution' of the file bytes inside the filesystem... If you can't clone, you need to find a way to control that too.

Comment: I'm intrigued by the freezing of the clock idea. Is this something that's easy to do? And actually in my situation, the build machine for the regulatory agency is one we provided for them, and it's used only for building our software. So I can kinda do whatever I want with that system.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try [`e2image`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/e2image.8.html):

> The e2image program will save critical ext2, ext3, or ext4 filesystem
> metadata located on device to a file.

Despite that by default `e2image` saves metadata only, it's able to save data too, by the use of `-a` option. (See section "Including data" by the link)

> The -a option can be specified to include all data. This will give an image that is suitable to use to clone the entire FS or for backup purposes. Note that this option only works with the raw or QCOW2 formats.

QCOW2 format is more preferable for backups than raw format. QCOW2 image is a normal file with size that is close to used space of partition to back up. Raw image is a sparse file with all the implications - tools that don't handle sparse files specifically will process not only used space, but free space too.

So, usage examples are:

- Backup `sda1` partition, including files & metadata, to the file `boot-part.qcow2`:

```
sudo mount -o remount,ro /dev/sda1
sudo e2image -a -Q /dev/sda1 boot-part.qcow2
```

Note that remounting as read-only is required to guarantee that no one will write to the partition, while backup is in progress. After all, you are able to remount as read-write by `sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda1` if you need to.

- Restore partition `/dev/sda1` from QCOW2 image file `boot-part.qcow2`:

```
sudo umount /dev/sda1
sudo e2image -r boot-part.qcow2 /dev/sda1
```

Note that `umount` is a must since you can't rewrite superblocks of a mounted partition. If `/dev/sda1` is not mounted that time, you can skip this step. :)

It's also worth noting that in restoring scenario size of `/dev/sda1` should be equal or greater than partition inside image file, otherwise you will get error: `e2image: Invalid argument while trying to convert qcow2 image (boot-part.qcow2) into raw image (/dev/sda1)`.